# jquery datatable receive incorect json from webAPI

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

i can't populate a jQuery Datatble from ajax command.

this is webAPI code (UtentiController):

```
' GET: api/Utenti
    <HttpGet>
    Public Function GetUtentis() As IEnumerable(Of Utenti)
         Using WFe As WorkForceEntities = New WorkForceEntities
            Return WFe.Utentis.ToList
         End Using
    End Function
```

this is client side code:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
            paging: true,
            sort: true,
            searching: true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/api/utenti/',
                "type": "get",
                "datatype": "json",
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Nome", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Cognome", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Username", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "GruppoDiLavoro", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "ProfiloFunzionalità", "autoWidth": true },
              ]
        })


    })
</script>
```

i think the problem is on json string. the ajax command return incorrect json, missing the initial substring **{"data":**

> [
>       {
>         "IDutente": 2,
>         "Operatore": "Admin",
>         "Password": "1234",
>         "LivelloDiAccesso": 1,
>         "Nome": "Admin",
>         "Cognome": "Admin",
>         "Username": "Admin",
>         "GruppoDiLavoro": "Admin",
>         "ProfiloFunzionalità": "Admin",
>         "Attivo": true,
>         "DataCreazione": "2017-08-30T00:00:00",
>         "DataScadenza": "2025-12-31T00:00:00",
>         "Mail": "nothing"
>       },
>       {
>         "IDutente": 3,
>         "Operatore": "MS",
>         "Password": "1234",
>         "LivelloDiAccesso": 2,
>         "Nome": "Admin",
>         "Cognome": "S",
>         "Username": "M",
>         "GruppoDiLavoro": "Admin",
>         "ProfiloFunzionalità": "Admin",
>         "Attivo": true,
>         "DataCreazione": "2017-08-30T00:00:00",
>         "DataScadenza": "2025-12-31T00:00:00",
>         "Mail": "nothing"
>       }
>     ]

if i load a json file like this (**"ajax": "../UtentiData.json",**)

> {
>     "data": [
>       {
>         "IDutente": 2,
>         "Operatore": "Admin",
>         "Password": "1234",
>         "LivelloDiAccesso": 1,
>         "Nome": "Admin",
>         "Cognome": "Admin",
>         "Username": "Admin",
>         "GruppoDiLavoro": "Admin",
>         "ProfiloFunzionalità": "Admin",
>         "Attivo": true,
>         "DataCreazione": "2017-08-30T00:00:00",
>         "DataScadenza": "2025-12-31T00:00:00",
>         "Mail": "nothing"
>       },
>       {
>         "IDutente": 3,
>         "Operatore": "MS",
>         "Password": "1234",
>         "LivelloDiAccesso": 2,
>         "Nome": "Admin",
>         "Cognome": "S",
>         "Username": "M",
>         "GruppoDiLavoro": "Admin",
>         "ProfiloFunzionalità": "Admin",
>         "Attivo": true,
>         "DataCreazione": "2017-08-30T00:00:00",
>         "DataScadenza": "2025-12-31T00:00:00",
>         "Mail": "nothing"
>       }
>     ]
>   }

the code work well and the jQuery Datatable is populate correctly.

what can i do to work fine with Json webAPI?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a "Flat array data source".

Change your code to:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
        paging: true,
        sort: true,
        searching: true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/api/utenti/',
            "type": "get",
            "dataSrc": "",
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Nome", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "Cognome", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "Username", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "GruppoDiLavoro", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "ProfiloFunzionalità", "autoWidth": true },
          ]
    })


})
```

See the [example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html).

Comment: now i have another problem. If i use a url like '/api/utenti/1', the datatables report "No data available in table"!! where is the problem?

Comment: Did you open the url in your webbrowser and check if there is data available?

Comment: ok. i resolve. the problem in on API web code...it return a worng JSON string. if i return a List(Of T), it's all OK...